# Sheet To Workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have found the below code to save sheet as new workbook but what I wanted to know if it is possible to change the save name
each time the macro is run to the value on sheet 1 in cells B2 and to a specific file location.

I have tried the way below and it just simply saves the file with the name of the file location instead of saving it in the file location specified.

```
Sub sb_Copy_Save_Worksheet_As_Workbook() 
    Dim wb As Workbook 
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1) 
    wb.SaveAs "C:\temp\test1.xlsx" 
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

many thanks

Jamie

Comment: The name of the file is in **B2**, where is the file location stored ??

Answer (score 1):

Let's say "Sheet1" has in cell **B2** the value "test1" (the filename), then you can use the following:

```
Sub sb_Copy_Save_Worksheet_As_Workbook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFilename As String
    Dim myFileExtension As String
    myPath = "C:\temp\" 'you can change this
    myFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    myFilename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.SaveAs myPath & myFilename & myFileExtension
    wb.Close False
End Sub
```

If your cell **B2** already includes the file extension (so it is "test1.xlsx" in B2), just remove the `myFileExtension` parts from the code.

The folder, where you want to save your file has to exist. If you need help checking this or creating the folder in your macro, please leave a comment.

Comment: Perfect Thank you Ever so much

Comment: is there any way that you could run that Sub and after it has executed the above to return you to the original work book?

Comment: This is actually done. The last line `wb.Close False` closes the created workbook containing the Sheet2. So the only workbook that should still be open is the one you are running the macro on.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding on the cell value to the path string like this:

```
Sub sb_Copy_Save_Worksheet_As_Workbook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.SaveAs "C:\temp\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

File extension will default to `.xlsx` even if the original file is `.xlsm` so you don't need to add this to the path string.